# Java mkdir() folder in which you can't create subfolders or files ( throw access denied)

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, junit

> We want to add 100% coverage on our Spring Boot Java program we run so there are 2
>   strange tests that require us to create a folder and a file with access
>   permission denied .

For the file was pretty straight forward :

```
File file = new file(....path...);
.... just creating the file with some simple code...
//now deny permissions
file.setReadable(false);
file.setWritable(false);

//Some code trying to write on that file
throwing exception (happy junit test is passed)
```

**But the i want to create a directory let's name it `parentDir` and make it impossible the same java program can create files or folders inside it.So in the same logic** :

```
File parentDir= new file(....parentDirPath...);
parentDir.mkDir();
parentDir.setReadable(false);
parentDir.setWritable(false);

//Some code to create another folder inside the parentDir
File childDir= new file(....parentDirPath/childDir...);
directoryExistsOrElseCreate(childDir.toPath());

//WHOT IT CREATES THE FOLDER even if i don't want ...
```

Why it is still able to create new files and folders on the `parentDir`?

---

Update , just digged into the code and found out that we are using `Files.createDirectories(path);` instead of `file.mkDir();`

The method i am testing is this :

```
public void directoryExistsOrElseCreate(final Path path) {

    try {
        if (Files.notExists(path)) {
            log.warn("Directory={} does NOT EXIST, creating...", path);
            Files.createDirectories(path);
        } else {
            log.warn("Directory={} ALREADY EXISTS, skipping...", path);
        }
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        log.error("Error during creating directory: path={}, error={}", path.toString(), e.getMessage());
        throw new AtsGenericException(AtsGenericErrorCode.IO_ERROR, new Object[]{e.getMessage()});
    }
}
```

Comment: Which operating systems are you running on? Is the other code run as administrator?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Hello Peter :)

 `Using Windows 10 , Running as Administrator` . The code should be platform independent though .

Comment: Try not running as Administrator.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Why that happens though ? Doesn't the admin has all the permissions . Why it works for files and not for folders ? All the code is Deployed Using Bamboo Attlasian after i create it locally ...

Comment: @PeterLawrey  Actually i am just running the program from Eclipse , if that makes a change .

Comment: Actually, you're using code which is not platform independent. Underneath the covers `File` uses a `FileSystem` implementation, which in your case most likely ends up calling Win32 functions; Same for `Files` (https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/nio/file/Files.java). There's no guarantee that methods like `setReadable()` and `setWritable()` produce the same result across all platforms. What are the exact Windows permissions which are being set by your code?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Well Emannuel i am running the code from Eclipse in Windows 10 as administrator and i am using exactly the code shown on the question :) `file.setReadable(false);
file.setWritable(false);`

Comment: I understand, @GOXR3PLUS. But to determine the root cause you're going to have to look at the directory created by your test and see what the permissions are. The problem is Windows permissions are more granular than simply read and write, so it's not clear how those methods map to actual permissions.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have only one answer for you: don't waste your energy getting 100% code coverage. There are plenty of situations where it's not worth the effort and thus a waste of time and money. Moreover, convoluted tests to cover hard-to-test things like private constructors, exceptions from utility classes or direct interactions with the system (file, network etc) are hard to understand and maintain. They only add technical debt to your application without adding any value at all.

Don't write separate unit tests for anemic model classes either (i.e. POJO's with only fields, getters and setters and no logic). These classes should be used elsewhere and covered as part of other tests.

Set a goal in the range 60-80% and focus your test writing efforts on your business and transformation logic, e.g. controllers, mappers, services. This is the logic that is hard to understand, changes most often and determines the functionality of your application.

To cover misconfigurations or bugs in any uncovered code, write some basic integration (end-to-end) tests using stubbed environment components like an H2 database, or a WireMock endpoint with a canned response. These will show if your system fails to interact at a basic level much better than any cooked up reflection ridden unit tests can.

Comment: I'm sad about the downvote. Sometimes the answer to a question is not to go along with the poster's assumptions, but challenge them, providing good arguments to do so. You may not agree with my arguments, but I think they don't deserve downvoting.

Comment: Probably because your answer is not 100% according to StackOverflow spirit. Having said that, your are 100% right in your argument :)

Comment: It's worth remembering that even 100% coverage isn't enough. You can test 3 features work, but they might work in combination.

Comment: Your comment is an opinion about a detail (code coverage) and not the answer to the real question (how to create a folder and a file with access permission denied)

Comment: This sort of attitude really irks me. Every post and comment here reflects an opinion, so don't discredit my answer as 'just an opinion' please. I was trying to help the OP by challenging the assumptions at the top of the post and to avoid doing futile work. Less code is always better than more code. And don't feed the hungry but teach them to fish.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir()), in your scenario, `mkdir()` should return `false`, and not throw an exception.

Comment: Just updated the question , sorry if i make this answer invalid .... i still kept the file.mkdir() because your answer is helpful .

Comment: I just added the method we are testing .

Comment: Thank you. I see that your code catches an IOException, and just prints it (and then continues as usual). This code will also not throw an exception, due to the catch clause.

Comment: Ouuu damn me forgot something again .... ffff it throws a business specific exception ... edited the code .. it throws `throw new AtsGenericException(AtsGenericErrorCode.IO_ERROR, new Object[]{e.getMessage()});`